# Mocking component methods that return promise

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I need to create unit test for the following prototype method `validateAddress`:

```
import MyService from 'api/my-service';
import staticData from 'static-data';
import constants from 'utilities/constants';
import locale from 'api/locale-provider';

    const myService = new MyService();
    /**
     * @param {Object} values
     * @param {String} currency
     * @param {Object} userProfile
     * @returns {Promise<boolean>}
     */
    export const validateAddress = (
        values,
        currency,
        userProfile
    ) => {
        const countryCode = locale.getCountry();
        if (
            staticData.type === constants.BILLING_MANAGER &&
            (countryCode === 'CA' || countryCode === 'US')
        ) {
            const payload = makeAddressPayload({
                values,
                currency
            });

            return myService
                .postAddress(payload, userProfile)
                .then(() => {
                    return true;
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    return false;
                });
        }
        return true;
    };

    const makeAddressPayload = ({
       values,
       paymentProcessor,
       currency
    }) => ({
       ...
    });
```

Does anyone know how I can mock `MyService` class method `postAddress`?

```
class MyService {

    constructor(options = {}) {
       ...
    }

    postAddress(payload, userProfile) {
    let promise = authorizedFetchRequest(
            ...
        );

        promise = fetchTimeoutHandler(promise);
        return promise;
    }
}

export default MyService;
```

Answer (score 1):

For your case, you can use the [mockImplementationOnce](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationoncefn) method to mock the response for `postAddress` request.

This is how you can spy on it as part of your test,

```
it('should call postAddress', () => {
  jest.spyOn(MyService, 'postAddress').mockImplementationOnce(() => (
    ...expected response
  ));
});
```

Comment: do I just call constructor at the beginning, i.e. myService = new MyService() every time?

Comment: For the above question, are you referring to your test/spec file? Or your component file?

Comment: In the test, do I do new MyService()?

Comment: for some reason the test went in the real postAddress method... I used your example... Not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: There is no need to initialise `myService = new MyService() ` in that test. You can just import `MyService` on the top of your test,  and then spy on it as shown at my example. Let me make an edit as there is a typo on my code snippet..

Comment: I am getting "Error: Cannot spy the postAddress property because it is not a function; undefined given instead". Thanks for trying anyways!

Comment: Hmm.. How about initialising `myService = new MyService()`, and then using jest.spyOn(myService, 'postAddress') to spy instead?

Comment: that was calling real postAddress

Answer (score 0):

I took suggestion from wentjun and ended up implementing it as such:

```
const spy = jest
      .spyOn(MyService.prototype, 'postAddress')
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
          return new Promise(resolve => {
                resolve(fixtures.addressPostSuccess);
          });
      });
```

And if I wanted to mock failure:

```
const spy = jest
      .spyOn(MyService.prototype, 'postAddress')
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
           return new Promise((resolve, error) => {
                error(fixtures.addressPostFailure);
           });
      });
```